# Spring JPA repoistory findBy IN List - allow null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, findby

**Short Description**

How do I make `findBy<Field>In` work with `IN` when the array list input is null. e.g. ignore it.  What would your DAO for this look like?

**Longer description.**

Imagine you have creating a search for users page.

in the application.  You have various options to filter on.

- created  (date range always given)
- Country  (when null ignore and search all countries)
- AgeRange
- Job Title
- etc...

Now say you want to search for all users in a given date range in a list of countries.

When searching for users I will always search for a date joined however if I have not selected a country I want it to search for all countries.

I am planning on adding several more filter options other than country.  So I don't really want to create lots of findBy methods for each possible field combination.

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<BeatRate> findByCreatedBetweenAndCountryIn(Date from, Date to, ArrayList<String> countryList );

}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {

    Date from = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" ).parse( "2015-01-01" );
    Date to   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2015-05-15");

    //ArrayList<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //countryList.add("UK");
    //countryList.add("Australia");
    //countryList.add("Japan");   // works ok when I have a list

    countryList = null;  // I want it to search for all countries when this is null -- this errors and doesnt work..  

    List<BeatRate> beatRates = beatRateDao.findByCreatedBetweenAndRentalCountryIn(from, to, countryList);

    Assert.assertTrue(beatRates.size()>0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two methods:

```
beatRateDao.findByCreatedBetweenAndRentalCountryIn(from, to, countryList);
```

and

```
beatRateDao.findByCreatedBetweenAndRental(from, to);
```

Then simply pick one based on `countryList`:

```
List<BeatRate> beatRates = (countryList != null && !countryList.isEmpty())
    ?  beatRateDao.findByCreatedBetweenAndRentalCountryIn(from, to, countryList)
    : beatRateDao.findByCreatedBetweenAndRental(from, to);
```

The IN clause requires a non-nullable and non empty argument list as otherwise the query will fail.

On PostgreSQL, if you try to run a query like this:

```
select * 
from product 
where quantity in ( )
```

you get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3: where quantity in ( )
                            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 45
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  The problem is I have several filters.  Status, Country, City, Users... Sometimes Country exists sometimes not sometimes you want Status and Country but not City.. etc..  It results in a lot of combinations so im not sure the above method is the best way?.

Comment: Criteria API works best for dynamic filters. Spring Data doesn't work with null arguments.

Comment: what is Criteria API?

Comment: [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) is a JPA type-safe dynamic query builder API.

Comment: @VladMihalcea is correct. You should check out [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884192/best-way-to-create-jpa-query-that-might-contain-a-parameter-or-might-not/).

Comment: If you want to construct a query based on arbitrary constraints I recommend to look into [Querydsl](http://querydsl.com/). It's by far the nicest API to assemble predicates on the fly. Spring Data derived query methods are rather targeted to use cases where you have a static set of constraints. See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) on Spring Data integration with Querydsl.

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm I have the exact same issue. Multiple findBy In List criterias which can be null. Is your comment still valid for 2020 or would you use an other approach today?